# Display data through foreign key in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

in Index.php from my View of Turno I have this:

```
<?php foreach ($turnos as $turno): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $turno->has('cancha') ? $this->Html->link($turno->cancha->idCancha, ['controller' => 'Canchas', 'action' => 'view', $turno->cancha->idCancha]) : '' ?></td>
    </tr>
```

This code works right. **BUT** I want to show the id of "Complejo", and "Complejo" is the foreign key of "Cancha". **So... I want to navigate twice.. Something like this:**

```
    <?php foreach ($turnos as $turno): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $turno->has('cancha')->('complejo') ? $this->Html->link($turno->cancha->complejo->idComplejo, ['controller' => 'Canchas', 'action' => 'view', $turno->cancha->->complejo->idComplejo]) : '' ?></td>
    </tr>
```

But is not working. How can I navigate twice? The connection between "Turno" and "Cancha" is Ok and the connection between "Cancha" and "Complejo" is ok.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The relationship between tables are:

**In ComplejosTable:**

```
$this->hasMany('Canchas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'complejoFK'
    ]);
```

**In CanchasTable:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Complejos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'complejoFK',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

$this->hasMany('Turnos', [
    'foreignKey' => 'canchaFK'
    ]);
```

**In TurnosTable:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Canchas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'canchaFK',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Comment: Please check this link answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839258/cakephp-how-to-retrieve-deeply-associated-data

Comment: Probably you need to do: `$turno->has('cancha') && $turno->cancha->has('complejo') ? `. Anyway please explain the relatonships between your Tables.

Comment: @arilia I've just posted the relationship between tables. I'm trying this but is not working: 
<td><?= $turno->has('cancha') && $turno->cancha->has('complejo') ? $this->Html->link($turno->cancha->complejo->idComplejo, ['controller' => 'Complejos', 'action' => 'view', $turno->cancha->complejo->idComplejo]) : '' ?></td>

Comment: Sorry @Anant but I don't know how to implement that with my db. In my TurnosController index() function i have this: public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Canchas','Usuarios']
        ];

        $this->set('turnos', $this->paginate($this->Turnos));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['turnos']);
    }

Comment: what do you mean with 'is not working'? You have an error? Also: when you retrieve your $turnos are you containing Canchas and Canchas.Complejos too?

Comment: @arilia have a empty cell. No data is displaying, but also no error display, just column empty

Comment: and what about contain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115517/discussion-between-federick-jons-and-arilia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `Complejos` to the contained Tables

```
'contain' => ['Canchas', 'Canchas.Complejos', 'Usuarios']
```

so you can do

```
 <?= $turno->has('cancha') && $turno->cancha->has('complejo') ?
     $this->Html->link($turno->cancha->complejo->nombre,  [
        'controller' => 'Complejos',
        'action' => 'view', 
        $turno->cancha->complejo->id_complejo
     ]) : '' ?>
```

Comment: Workingggggggggggggggggg!! Thanks